# Using PHPOffice/phpspreadsheet with PHP+Apache Ubuntu

Tags: apache, laravel-9, phpspreadsheet, ubuntu-22.04, php-8.2

I use the **PhpSpreadsheet library** in my Laravel app which runs on a **PHP8.2 server + Apache(Laragon) on Windows 10**; everything works fine locally. I load an xlsx file, edit it and save with no problem.

But that I deploy the application (the same code) on the online server **(PHP2.4+Apache on Ubuntu)**; the Apache server crashes; after investigating, I realized that it is from the line where we use the library (**$reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');**);

Sorry someone help me ..... do not hesitate, I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 weeks in vain

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: why are you using `PHP2.4` on online server? or is it a typo in the question?